# Get Epic Link for issue via jira-python

Tags: jira, python-jira

When I request a Jira issue via python-jira (`jira_session.issue("<KEY>")`), the result does not contain the "Epic Link". Can I request to include it or do I need to do a separate query for each issue to get its Epic link?

Answer (score 0):

Is Epic Link in the fields that you see in the issue in the UI?
However https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-62296 indicates it may be the Epic Name rather than the issue key of the Epic?

Comment: Tested this just now and it looks like the field value returned is in fact the issue key of the Epic in Epic Link

Comment: Thanks for the hint that the value of the field is the key of the Epic! Turned out that the epic link field is called customfield_... here.